# ExceptionHandling with Unity and VirtualMethodInterceptor

Tags: c#, exception, unity-container, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I've configurated exception handling in app using Enterprise Library Configurator (Simple: Added new policy for all exception, added handler which passes to Logging Block. Than it is written to Windows Event System)

However, when I'm instantiating my objects using VirtualMethodInterceptor - it doesn't handle any exception. When I switch to TransparentProxyInterceptor - it works.

I use code for creating object like that:

```
_container.RegisterType<T, TK>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(), 
            new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>())
```

What's the problem? TransparentProxyInterceptor is slow, and it is better not to use it.

I use Unity 5.0

Upd. Forgot to say: I'm using an attribute to indicate methods that should be handled:
        [ExceptionCallHandler("Policy")]

Comment: Hi, it's hard to tell - can you show us the code on the Behaviour and the code that fails?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my problem - missed VirtualMethodInterceptor and InterfaceInterceptor.

Thanks